# Poster session includes a "poster" + "article"?

Tags: computer-science, poster, workshop

When we are accepted in a **poster session**, does it mean that we need to provide a "**poster**" (usually in **A0** size) + an "**article**" which explains the topic **in a separate file** ? Or both poster and article are included in a single PDF file ?

And also this article must include an "abstract" like usual papers?

I ask this question because I have received a strange email from a workshop as follows :

> ***Posters have to  be formatted in LNCS-style and not exceed 1 page in
>   length, with a PDF  draft of the proposed poster included as page 2 of
>   the submission (A0 size  in portrait mode,  W 841mm x H 1189 mm, with
>   all fonts embedded in the  PDF file). In addition, poster titles
>   should always start with the  phrase "Poster Abstract:"***

**Here is the website of the conference :** http://deic.uab.cat/conferences/cbt/cbt2018/

.

Answer (score 1):

It'd the best to ask conference organizers for the clarification. Organizers of conferences are usually very friendly and quite responsive, so there's no harm in asking. And they will be able to give the precise and authoritative answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better ask the orgs.

I was a poster's chair and also have published/presented some posters. The typical procedure is that the "paper" (which is rather called a poster abstract and is typically a 2-4 page document) is reviewed. The poster is shown at the conference.

This procedure might be somewhat historical, as communicating posters to the reviewers was previously hard. Also, you need a chance to show not only the poster, but what you are saying, when standing next to it. Hence, the poster abstract.